# Can't edit JSON array through PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, post

So I want to edit an item in a n associative array in a json file through PHP. The newcontent and index come from a javascript that sends them to this php file through POST. 
The JSON file looks like this:

```
[{"title":"This is a title","content":"foo bar","date":"Friday 25th May 2018 
10:52:01 PM"}]
```

And the PHP:

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_POST['newcontent']) && isset($_POST['index'])) {
 $data = file_get_contents("news.json"); 
 $decoded = json_decode($data); 

 $index = $_POST['index'];
 $newcontent = htmlspecialchars($_POST['newcontent']);
 $newdate = date('l jS F Y h:i:s A');
 $decoded[$index]["content"] = $newcontent;
 $decoded[$index]["date"] = $newdate;

 $output = json_encode($decoded);
 file_put_contents("news.json", $output);
 }
?>
```

So what this should do is pick the right array element in the json through the index value. Then change the value of the "content" key to the $newcontent which it got from POST, and the value of the "date" key to the $newdate. Then write it back to the json file "news.json".  But it just doesn't want to edit the file. It doesn't give me an error, it just does nothing. The file remains unchanged. I checked in the console and the POST works fine.

EDIT: after some further testing I discovered that the condition isset($_POST['newcontent'] doesn't return true so the rest of the code doesn't actually run

Comment: Show us the JSON file. Also, why are you doing this? It seems like you're writing your own database here. Have you looked at using [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) or some other database?

Comment: This would be what the JSON file looks like [{"title":"This is a title","content":"foo bar","date":"Friday 25th May 2018 10:52:01 PM"}] I have no trouble deleting elements from this array with php but editing them gives me problems. Why am I doing this? Well im mainly a python guy and wanted to get acquainted with javascript and php.

Comment: Add it to your question. Also add **what you're trying to do**. I get the feeling you're trying to get around using a database.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the optional second argument to `json_decode()`, so that it will create associative arrays rather than objects.

```
$decoded = json_decode($data, true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: What is the value of `$index`? What does `var_dump($decoded[$index]);` show?